# add parameter value in a Viewbag one by one mvc c# razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am passing class name as a parameter from view to the controller using html actionlink and storing those value in a ViewBag. I want to add all parameter value to add in the ViewBag every time I post from the view page. Now I am getting only the current posting parameter value, not the previous values. Or there is any other way I can achieve this.

Thanks

Updated -

Model class -

```
public string Link_id { get; set; }
public string Link_class { get; set; }
```

Controller –

```
public ActionResult R_Class(r_item Link_id, r_item Link_class)
        {            
            Show_Page();

            ModelState.Clear(); 

            return View(new r_item());
        }

Private Void Show_Page()
{
    r_item r_class = new r_item ();
    r_class.Link_class = Request.Form["Link_class"];
}
```

View page –

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{                    
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Link_class)

 @Html.ActionLink(Model.Link_class, "R_Class", "R_Class", null,
new { Link_class = @row[2], @class = "Click_Link", onclick = "return false;" })
```

Comment: if you want to append the viewbag , its possible,  eg ViewBag.Message+="NewMessage";

Comment: The web is stateless. If you do not persist the value somewhere its lost.

Comment: @ARUN, I tried to append but getting only the current value, ViewBag.class_name += modelclass.m_class_name;

Comment: use ViewData["Message"]+="Message" , read about peeking in case this dont work

Comment: For transporting I use hidden fields

Comment: @ARUN, could you please give me an example, I am new in MVC

Comment: Please elaborate you requirement with some rough sketch about want really need, from this I could get only a little

Comment: @ARUN, please see the updated question, I have added what I am currently doing. I want to APPEND the parameter value every time I post the page, currently I am getting the current value not the previous parameter.

Comment: @arifpervez please comment on where to get the value, with an example description of your requirement,

Comment: @ARUN. I am getting value from database, for example, Link_id = 1, Link_class = A1. Also, I am getting the value correctly but everytime I am posting the page, I am getting the current value but I need to store somewhere all the submitted value previously with a separator like comma (,).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public ActionResult R_Class(r_item Link_id, r_item Link_class,hidden_value)
    {            
        Show_Page();

        ModelState.Clear(); 
        ViewBag.Msg = Link_id + hidden_value;

        return View(new r_item());
    }



using (Html.BeginForm())
{         
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Msg" name="hidden_value">



  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Link_class)



@Html.ActionLink(Model.Link_class, "R_Class", "R_Class", null,
new { Link_class = @row[2], @class = "Click_Link", onclick = "return false;" })

<input type=hidden name="Link_id" value="@model.Link_id">
<input type=hidden name="Link_class" value="@model.Link_class">
<input type="submit" onclick="return false;">

}
```

Buy I couldn't figure out the need of this , I have implemented the idea, customize it to your need

Comment: @arifpervez Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I have got it,

On your first posting you are getting the value in the action- right

For the next posting send the value back to view through the viewbag 
ViewBag.Msg = YourValue;

and store it in a hidden field

then the second view or page will have this previous data
append the value from the hidden field with the data from the new action parameters

Some modification might be needed , and a form to carry the data etc

Comment: Hi Arun, yes exactly what I am looking for, could you please help me how can I achieve this. Thanks